# Flutter - agora - how to make live streaming

Tags: flutter, live-streaming, agora.io

I want to make a live streaming call using agora between two apps. the first app is for the trainer who can make live streams for viewers who are users from the second app the trainer can see all cameras from his viewers in his session but users see only his camera. can anyone help me with some docs or articles, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Agora Flutter SDK, you will have to set the channel profile to `LiveBroadcasting` where you can set the user role to either a broadcaster or an audience member. For your particular use case, the trainer would be the broadcaster and the users would be the audience members. You can follow this blog to know more about Agora Live Video Streaming and how you can add it to your app: [https://www.agora.io/en/blog/adding-live-interactive-video-streaming-using-the-agora-flutter-sdk/](http://In%20the%20Agora%20Flutter%20SDK%20you%20will%20have%20to%20set%20the%20channel%20profile%20to%20%60LiveBroadcasting%60%20where%20you%20can%20set%20the%20user%20role%20to%20either%20a%20broadcaster%20or%20an%20audience%20member.%20For%20your%20particular%20use%20case%20the%20trainer%20would%20be%20the%20broadcaster%20and%20the%20the%20users%20would%20be%20the%20audience%20members.%20You%20can%20follow%20this%20blog%20to%20know%20more%20about%20Agora%20Live%20Video%20Streaming%20and%20how%20you%20can%20add%20it%20in%20your%20app:%20https://www.agora.io/en/blog/adding-live-interactive-video-streaming-using-the-agora-flutter-sdk/)